# D言語のローカル変数をキャプチャした構造体テンプレートがコンパイルできないです。

Tags: d

D言語のローカル変数をキャプチャした構造体テンプレートがコンパイルできないです。
やりたいこととしては
A->B->main
でBはAから呼ばれた関数の引数を加工してbfに流したいです。
どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
import std.stdio;

void main(){
    long n=3;
    auto a = B!(a=>a*n)();
    a.fun().writeln;
}

struct B(alias bf){
    A!(a=>bf(a+2)) s;
    long fun(){
        return s.fun();
    }
}
struct A(alias af){
    long fun(){
        return af(2);
    }
}
```

追記:
エラーメッセージです。

```
test.d(10): Error: function test.main.B!((a) => a * n).B.__lambda3 cannot access frame of function D main
test.d(10):        instantiated from here: A!((a) => bf(a + 2))
test.d(5):        instantiated from here: B!((a) => a * n)
Failed: ["/usr/bin/dmd", "-v", "-o-", "test.d", "-I."]
```

Comment: コンパイル時のエラーメッセージ等も質問文に含めておくと、より回答しやすいかなと思います :)

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記しました。